# How to recycle(or flush) an IPV6 node's global address by RA(router advertisement)?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm developing on linux router to assign global IP for node linked. The node I am testing on is a Windows PC.
I managed to assign global IP by sending Router Advertisement as per rfc4861.

+---------+---------------+----------+
07:14:07,632,019   ETHER
|0   |33|33|00|00|00|01|ce|74|19|9a|07|a2|86|dd|60|00|00|00|00|38|3a|ff|fe|80|00|00|00|00|00|00|cc|74|19|ff|fe|94|01|9c|ff|02|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|01|86|00|a1|25|40|40|ff|ff|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|03|04|40|c0|ff|ff|ff|ff|ff|ff|ff|ff|00|00|00|00|fc|01|ab|ab|cd|cd|ef|e0|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|05|01|00|00|00|00|05|dc|

After sending this RA from router (link-local addr fe80::cc74:19ff:fe94:19c), the tested PC can be auto-configured with global addr fc01:abab:cdcd:efe0:e1fb:2297:51db:af84 and fc01:abab:cdcd:efe0:29e9:52fd:2527:dbca.

Above is background.

But how can I recycle(or flush) the global IP on the tested PC? I have tried sending RA with (M=0,O=0,Router Lifetime=0), to my understanding to rfc4861, but this doesn't work. After that still I can see the global IP assigned, checking by cmd ipconfig.

Comment: The addresses in `fc00::/7` are _not_ Global addresses. Those are ULA addresses, and they are in the reserved part (`fc00::/8`) of the ULA range that you are not allowed to use. You can use ULA addresses in the `fd00::/8` range, but the next 40 bits are required to be randomly chosen.

Comment: Hi, Ron, thanks for your reply. Sorry that I didn't mention, we use a ROHDE&SCHWAR callbox to do the test. So the global address is simulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFC4862 could answer this question:

A RA with short "preferred lifetime" (like 1s) could deprecate the old IPv6 address, but which still may count as valid address. Back to current question, the address is not easy to be flushed by short "valid lifetime" because the consideration of avoiding DOS attack.

If someone who does need to flush the old IP, please refer to RFC4862 5.5.3:

*If RemainingLifetime is less than or equal to 2 hours, ignore the Prefix Information option with regards to the valid lifetime, unless the Router Advertisement from which this option was obtained has been authenticated (e.g., via Secure Neighbor Discovery [RFC3971]). If the Router Advertisement was authenticated, the valid lifetime of the corresponding address should be set to the Valid Lifetime in the received option.*